# How do I implement OnMessage (ResendRequest) on Quickfix crack?

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixn

What is the best approach to handle the ResendRequest message?

```
        public void OnMessage(QuickFix.FIX44.ResendRequest message, QuickFix.SessionID sessionId)
        {}
```

Comment: This is a session-level message and will be handled automatically by QuickFIX/n.

Comment: @ChristophJohn, you need to submit that as an answer!

Comment: I did now, thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a session-level message and will be handled automatically by QuickFIX/n.